# How can we compare the number was less than

Tags: c, algorithm, math, complexity-theory

**Edit**

I want to get the divisor of natural numbers N.

```
for (int i=1;i<n/2;i++)
 if(n%i==0)
    print(i);
```

How can we compare the number was less than n/2 ?
I  wants to find all the factors in less than n/2 steps

Comment: I removed the Mathematica tag, I don't see it as applicable here.

Comment: It should be n%i==0 for starters.

Comment: Just a general note on all answers below who do i <= sqrt(n), it's almost always better to check i*i <= n.

Comment: guys... using sqrt(n) is not correct if you are looking for all factors.

Comment: @John Note that in my answer I am going up to `sqrt(n)` but printing both `i` and `n/i` when I find a factor.  Thus, they are all being found.  (There's a check for `i==sqrt(n)` to avoid printing the square root of a perfect square twice.)

Comment: @aelguindy I'm not convinced.  Since `n` is constant during the loop, `sqrt(n)` will be optimized out of the loop and only happen once, while `i*i` will have to be evaluated each time.  There's a break-even point (at fairly small `n`) above which `sqrt(n)` is faster and below which the efficiency really won't matter.

Comment: @AaronDufour Maybe it is gcc being stupid on Mac. I compile -O3 -S, I look at the assembly and sqrt is there in every iteration.

Comment: @aelguindy I did the same compilation and its definitely outside of the loop (although if I hard-code in a value for `n`, the compiler does the `sqrt` and hard-codes that in).  I'm also on a Mac, and I see the top of the loop labelled by `LBB2_2` and the `sqrtsd` 9 lines above that.  I'm compiling the code from my answer, with `n = atoi(argv[1])` instead of `n = 25`.

Comment: @AaronDufour I am reading n with scanf, are you sure sqrt is not called again under label LBB1_4?

Comment: @aelguindy I don't have that label, but a find all on "sqrt" only finds the one occurence.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to determine if `i` is less than `n/2`?

Try this:

```
if (i < n/2)
    print(i);
```

Comment: I think the Ma wants to find all the factors in less than n/2 steps.

Comment: Ahh, I thought that this was a bit simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this in `sqrt(n)` steps, as follows:

```
for(int i = 1;i <= sqrt(n);i++)
{
  if(n % i == 0)
  {
    print(i);
    if(i != sqrt(n))
      print(n / i);
  }
}
```

This will print each divisor of `n` once.  Note that, like in the example code, I have assumed a `print` function that could be implemented as follows:

```
void print(int i)
{
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: @MaEb Its not completely clear what you're looking for.  This correctly prints all of the factors of `n`.  For `n = 24`, it prints `1 24 2 12 3 8 4 6`.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
```

and

```
for(int i=1;i<n/2;i++)
```

works but the second is more efficient. The divisors of a number wouldn't exceed half of it.
For example, factors of 100 will definitely be less than and equal to 50.

There are many other efficient algorithms out [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Comment: Do you mean to write that the second is more efficient ?

Comment: If you take your idea one step further, you can go for sqrt(n) and not just n/2.

Comment: he is not going for prime number calculation. doing sqrt(100), the loop runs for i = 1 to 10 so you miss factors like 50.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for(int i=1;  i < (n/2); ++i)
    if (n%i==0)
         printf("%d\n",i);
```

how about this optimization (you need only up to the square root):

```
for(int i=1;  i < sqrt(n); ++i)
    if (n%i==0)
        printf("%d\n",i);
```

Or this one, you cover odd numbers only (useful if you check primes):

```
for(int i=1;  i < sqrt(n); i+=2)
    if (n%i==0)
         printf("%d\n",i);
```

Comment: for 16 this is bad.print 1,2,4

Comment: Note that, in your last example, `n=26` will only print `1`.  You can't skip `2` or evens will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for all divisors of some number N?

Try this:

```
for(int i=1;i<n/2;i++)
{
   if(n%i == 0)
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about first doing the division and storing in a variable so that it is not calculated on each iteration of the FOR loop:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(n/2);
for (int i = 1 ; i < num; i++)
```

Comment: That makes no sense on various levels. ToIn32? It's already an int32. Besides the tag is C, not C#. 'Optimizing' away that division? Sometimes a good idea, not in this case. It won't be a division anyway, and chances are it'll be moved outside the loop automatically.

Comment: This will almost always be done by the compiler anyway.  Don't bother.